# Create a matrix from list of files with file id as a column

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have around 8 files each of which is of the below format:

```
> head(data_1)
 V1
1  2.11
2  9.75
3 13.88
4 11.30
5  8.93
6 15.66
```

I am trying to create something like this:

```
file_id    V1
  1        data_from_1
  1        data_from_1
  2        data_from_2
   ......................
```

What I have so far is:

```
bind_row<-function(x, no, data){
return(rbind(data, matrix(c(no, x), ncol=2)))
}
all_data<-matrix(ncol=2, nrow=0)
apply(data_1, 1, bind_row, 1, all_data)
```

This returns all the list entries from data_1 as columns:

```
head(school_data)  
[,1] [,2]  [,3] [,4] [,5]  [,6]  [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
[1,] 1.00 1.00  1.00  1.0 1.00  1.00  1.00 1.00 1.00  1.00  1.00  1.00  1.00  1.00  1.00  1.00  1.00  1.00  1.00  1.00  
[2,] 2.11 9.75 13.88 11.3 8.93 15.66 16.38 4.54 8.86 11.94 12.47 11.11 11.65 14.53  9.61  7.38  3.34  9.06  9.45  5.98  
[,21] [,22] [,23] [,24] [,25]  
[1,]  1.00   1.0  1.00  1.00  1.00
[2,]  7.44   8.5  1.55 11.45  9.73
```

How do I achieve this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can place all the datasets in a `list` and use `rbindlist`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(mget(paste0("data_", 1:8)), idcol="file_id")
```

Using a reproducible example

```
 data_1 <- data.frame(V1 = c(2.11, 9.75, 13.88, 11.30, 8.93,15.66))
 data_2 <- data.frame(V1 = c(2.5, 5.3, 12.5))
 rbindlist(mget(paste0("data_", 1:2)), idcol="file_id")
```